# Enrolling in an Online Masters Degree in Math

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records, online-degree

I am currently an American undergraduate student who is pursuing a B.S. in Mathematics. Upon graduation, I want to work in industry and pursue a masters degree at Indiana State University online. The degree is simply: M.S. in Mathematics.

The link is to that program is [here](https://www.indstate.edu/academics/online/graduate/mathematics).

I *eventually* would like to pursue a Ph.D in Mathematics (hopefully from Stevens Institute of Technology or Rutgers).

Since there is an in person version of this degree, my question is, wold a university be able to tell that I received my degree from doing the work online? The classes are the same I believe,  and seemingly up to par with other masters programs in terms of courses.

> Would there be any indication that the degree was completed online, or would I receive the same diploma? Accordingly, would an institution like Rutgers or Stevens Institute of Technology know that I pursued my degree online? Is there a marking on transcripts or diplomas that *makes note of this?* Are programs less likely to admit students who received degrees online (regionally accredited, of course) than traditional residential programs?

I would appreciate different insights from all, but am especially interested in responses from those who have received degrees from completing work online from ***regionally accredited*** universities with decent rapport within the academic community.

Comment: Short answer: no. Nobody will be able to tell you did your program online. This also seems like a question for the schools you are applying to.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Fair. My problem with this, however, is that if I make an inquiry to Rutgers or Stevens, they may be less willing to accept someone who did their degree online. Also...worth noting...is it would be much more difficult (if not nearly impossible) to obtain letters of recommendation and form valuable relationships with *online* professors. Also....source?

Comment: I would think this would be a question for Indiana State.  I imagine it might appear on your transcript, and there's a high possibility one of your letter writers will mention it.  Anyway, I'm not sure it's a good idea to try to hide something like this.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to get a master's, work in industry for a few years, and then go back for your PhD? After the PhD, do you want to return to industry or not?

Comment: @user37208 ideally, no.